# transactions with messages

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions

I am coding an app where users can deposit ether into their accounts and do stuff with it (Im using `web3.js` and `geth`). However I would like to have everyone deposit into one single account, and then have a database that knows how much of the total pool of ether in the single account belongs to each person.

I was wondering if there was a feature in Ethereum where users would be able to send a message along side their transactions? So that a specific code could be given to the user who is making a deposite, and once the serverside code of the app sees the code, it can know who sent the ether.

**QUESTION:** Does this functionality or a similar one exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction(transactionObject [, callback])
```

If you are using above function for executing the transaction, then there is a parameter available in which you send some message along with transaction as well.

> data: String - (optional) Either a byte string containing the
>   associated data of the message, or in the case of a contract-creation
>   transaction, the initialisation code.

This shall help you to send a message, along with a transaction.

Check this for more details - https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction